# How to parse json file to be Array in object Class?

Tags: json, klaxon, object-class

I got confused when Im try to parsing json in object class.
Im using klaxon but I just wonder how to read the file because I cannot use activity or application to add it into buffered object.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AmjA.png)

Comment: https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon  Are you using this library?

Comment: yes exactly. Im doing this lib and I gonna make an object class. or anythig simpler to do